# Tizen OS using React Native Web. Why My local video .mp4 file is not playing in physical device.Local video is playing perfectly in Tizen simulator

Tags: react-native, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

Here I am developing a movie ott application using react native web.
Everything working fine in my application. Except I am unable to play local video in my landing screen.

but In my landing screen I am playing a video which is in `.mp4` format, It's playing perfectly in tizen simulator but after installing the application in the physical device it's not playing.
Please help me in this.

Here is my `config.xml` file privilege:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
```

Comment: Would you add more detailed information? used tizen version, device spec, code snippet, etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LunchBasketball
Here Is few privileges & feature that i added in config.xml
<tizen:application id="*" package="*" required_version="2.3"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.internet"/>
 <access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
And also added privileges like internet, tv.inputdevice, 
and also
    <tizen:metadata key="http://tizen.org/metadata/app_ui_type/base_screen_resolution" value="extensive"/>
    <tizen:setting screen-orientation="landscape" context-menu="enable" background-support="disable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/>

Comment: @LunchBasketball 
Physical device Info:
1. Samsung TV, 
2. Version No: XE05/UAU7700 /AU7000C-U43AC1
3. Current Sofware Version:2210

Tizen Studio :
1. Tizen Studio Version: 5.5

Code Snippet:
<video
 width={'100%'}
height={'100%'}
autoPlay
muted
loop
className='video-player'
preload
onLoadedData={handleVideoLoad}>
<source src={'../../globalAssets/Images/iStreamOnbaordingAnimation.mp4'} type='video/mp4' />
</video>
Note: my video size is 18Mb

Answer (score 0):

It might be the resolution of video is too large.

You'd better to convert to HD 720p.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tizen simulator use the software decoder,  but TV use the Hardware decoder.
It is different.

1. You can try push the iStreamOnbaordingAnimation.mp4 to USB disk and try playback it to check whether HW support it.
2. Try add the permission to spec file:

   %post

chsmack -a User::Home %{/usr/apps/Your APP name/your file path/iStreamOnbaordingAnimation.mp4
chsmack -a User::Home %{/opt/usr/apps/Your APP name/your file path/iStreamOnbaordingAnimation.mp4